# Why does VIM show the Unicode code point and not the UTF-8 code value?

Tags: vim, encoding, unicode, utf-8

Consider this supposed line of code that I found in a PHP blog, note the quotes:

```
throw new Exception(“That's not a server name!”);
```

Those quotes are [RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) (Unicode code point: `U+201D`; UTF-8 hex-encoded value: `0xE2 0x80 0x9D`). Pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in VIM displays the following in the status bar:

```
<”> 8221, Hex 201d, Octal 20035
```

‏

**Why is the Unicode code point being displayed and not the UTF-8 code value?**

Considering that the file is stored as UTF-8 and it is the **terminal** translating the bytes into glyphs, I would expect VIM to show the raw value of the file (UTF-8 code value), not to translate it into a Unicode code point.

Comment: TIL new #Vim commands. Thank you for the question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why is the Unicode code point being displayed and not the UTF-8 code value?

Because you use `ga`:

```
<”> 8221, Hex 201d, Octal 20035
```

instead of `g8`:

```
e2 80 9d
```

Comment: Thank you romainl. Actually, I did read `:h ga` but did not read the `g8` section that came after it. I quote from `:h ga` "_Print the ascii value of the character under the cursor ... When the character is a non-standard ASCII character, ... the non-printable version is also given._" I guess that the text of that document may have been written before UTF-8 support and since both the Unicode code point and the UTF-8 code value are the same hexidecimal value for code points <=127 there was no need to make a distinction at the time.

Answer (score 13):

Because Vim is a **text editor** and works with text codepoints, *not* bytes. There is more than just one translation happening – when opening a file, the editor must decode it from the byte encoding to an internal representation (usually Unicode); when saving back to a file, or when displaying its contents on the terminal, the editor must encode the text back to bytes.

One reason for this is simple – the file and the terminal might be using *different* character sets. For example, you're editing some old documents in ISO 8859-13 or KOI8-R, and want them to show up correctly on a UTF-8 terminal.

The second reason, again, is that text editors work with text. For example, `”` is one character and its width is one terminal cell, regardless of its byte encoding (3 bytes in UTF-8, 1 byte in Windows-1257, 2 bytes in Shift-JIS, and so on). If Vim merely counted it as three bytes but the terminal showed it as one, it would result in vertical splits being misaligned, lines wrapped too soon, tabs appearing too narrow, and so on.

```
Instead of this...                ...you would see this.

┌───────────────────────────┐     ┌───────────────────────────┐
│She said, "Hello."         │     │She said, "Hello."         │
│                           │     │                           │
│She said, “Hello.”         │     │She said, “Hello.”     │
│                           │     │                           │
│Ji pasakė, „Sveiki“.       │     │Ji pasakė, „Sveiki“. │
└───────────────────────────┘     └───────────────────────────┘
```

Not to mention, you'd have to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> *three times* to delete a single character.

Comment: Thanks Grawity, your opening sentence makes the critical point.